# Monitor AC power adaptors keep dying

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, power-supply, power, adapter

After moving to a new apartment and using my computer for a few days, I heard a small explosion in the AC adaptor that powers my monitor, which of course got turned off. When I touched the adaptor, I found it was very hot. Cooling it didn't help. Changing the power cord didn't help. Deducing that it was dead, I went to buy another one.

After using the new one for two days, it died also, a burning smell coming out of it. Obviously I am not going to buy a third one without knowing what causes them to die this way.My second monitor is working fine, so I don't think the apartment's power supply is the problem.

Could it be that the monitor got hurt during the move, and causes AC adaptors to fry and die?

Comment: It’s conceivable that a not-exactly short circuit has happened, overloading the power supply. That would be like winning the jackpot, however, very unlikely – because your monitor still works.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not an expert, I think it's more likely that your new apartment has a power supply that fluctuates more than it should, and the monitor power supplies just happen to be particularly sensitive to voltage surges. I would suggest purchasing a surge suppressing extension socket as well as a new power supply, and connecting the monitor to the electricity supply through that.

Comment: My second monitor is of the same brand, same model and has the same power adaptor, and it works fine...